# How to test if @Valid annotation is working?

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-boot, hibernate-validator

I have the following unit test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = {EqualblogApplication.class})
@WebAppConfiguration
@TestPropertySource("classpath:application-test.properties")
public class PostServiceTest {
  // ...

  @Test(expected = ConstraintViolationException.class)
  public void testInvalidTitle() {
       postService.save(new Post());  // no title
  }
}
```

The code for `save` in `PostService` is:

```
public Post save(@Valid Post post) {
    return postRepository.save(post);
}
```

The `Post` class is marked with `@NotNull` in most fields.

The problem is: **no validation exception is thrown**.

However, this happens only in testing. **Using the application normally runs the validation and throws the exception.**

Note: I would like to do it automatically (on save) and not by manually validating and then saving (since it's more realistic).

Comment: dupplicated. See : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13745848/how-to-test-valid

Comment: that solution only gives a programmatic approach.:  validator.validateProperty(object, propertyName)
I wanted an implicit validation on save

Comment: The solution with `@Inject    MockMvc mvc;` look good to me ?

Comment: Well.. not bad.. but it assumes an MVC controller layer. What if I want to use @Valid to protect the layer below? (the service/business layer).... in that case there is no MVC involved. Additionally, it's not as transparent as doing just a "save" and expecting a validation (just like running the app).

Comment: well, i'm not sure about which componant in spring is responsible to process the validation.
You could test the validation itself, but you may need an integration test (full deploy) for testing if the @valid is processed. 
For testing the validation result, see exemple §101.2.1.5 at http://www.jmdoudoux.fr/java/dej/chap-validation_donnees.htm

Comment: You may want to dig about `MethodValidationPostProcessor`

Comment: great! it seems promising. thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This solution works with Spring 5. It should work with Spring 4 as well. (I've tested it on Spring 5 and SpringBoot 2.0.0).

There are three things that have to be there:

1. in the test class, provide a bean for method validation (PostServiceTest in your example)

Like this:

```
@TestConfiguration
static class TestContextConfiguration {
   @Bean
   public MethodValidationPostProcessor bean() {
      return new MethodValidationPostProcessor();
   }
}
```

2. in the class that has @Valid annotations on method, you also need to annotate it with @Validated (org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated) on the class level!

Like this:

```
@Validated
class PostService {
   public Post save(@Valid Post post) {
       return postRepository.save(post);
   }
}
```

3. You have to have a Bean Validation 1.1 provider (such as Hibernate Validator 5.x) in the classpath. The actual provider will be autodetected by Spring and automatically adapted.

More details in [MethodValidationPostProcessor documentation](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/4.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/beanvalidation/MethodValidationPostProcessor.html)

Hope that helps

Comment: This does not seem to be working with Junit 5. can you please help

Comment: @Saran It seems work with JUnit5 in my case.

Comment: can you tell the solution for quarkus ? @Valid annotation not working as expected. Not throwing validation error.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it by loading `ValidationAutoConfiguration.class` into context:

```
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { MyComponent.class, ValidationAutoConfiguration.class
public class MyComponentValidationTest {
  
  @Autowired
  private MyComponent myComponent;

  @Test
  void myValidationTest() {
    String input = ...;
    // static import from org.assertj.core.api.Assertions
    assertThatThrownBy(() -> myComponent.myValidatedMethod(input))
      .isInstanceOf(ConstraintViolationException.class)
      .hasMessageContaining("my error message");
  }

}
```

And MyComponent class:

```
@Component
@Validated
public class MyComponent {


  public void myValidatedMethod(@Size(min = 1, max = 30) String input) {
    // method body
  }

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add below dependency in your pom and your junit with mockmvc will work.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.1-b08</version>
</dependency>
```