# @Valid does not trigger validation in @Repository

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, bean-validation, jedis

I'm writing unit tests to check if the input validation works in my Spring Repository, but it doesn't look like it does.

Keeping it simple, I have a Repository class:

```java
@Repository
public class CustomerRepository {
    // Java client for Redis, that I extend as JedisConnector in order to make it a Bean
    private Jedis jedis;

    @Autowired
    public CustomerRepository(JedisConnector jedis) {
        this.jedis = jedis;
    }

    private <S extends Customer> S save(@Valid S customer) throws CustomerException {
        try {
            this.jedis.set(...);  // writing to Redis (mocked in test)
            return customer;
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            throw new CustomerException(e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

This uses the following model class:

```java
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data // from Lombok
public class Customer {
    @Email(message = "Email must be valid.")
    private String identifier;

    @NotBlank(message = "Password cannot be null or empty string.")
    private String password;

    @URL(message = "URL must be a url.")
    private String url;
}
```

So I wrote a unit test like this, expecting it to throw some exception that I could assert:

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {JedisConnector.class})
public class CustomerRepositoryTest {
    // Cannot autowire because dependent bean needs to be configured
    private CustomerRepository customerRepository;

    @MockBean
    JedisConnector jedisConnector;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        // Configure Mock JedisConnector
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        Mockito.when(jedisConnector.select(anyInt())).thenReturn("OK");

        // Manually wire dependency
        customerRepository = new CustomerRepository(jedisConnector);
    }


    @Test
    public void saveShouldFailOnInvalidInput() throws CustomerException {
        Mockito.when(jedisConnector.set(anyString(), anyString())).thenReturn("OK");
        // Blatantly invalid input
        Customer customer = new Customer("testemail", "", "testurl");
        customerRepository.save(customer);
    }
}
```

But it just runs through, only outputting debug messages (that I left out in this question). **How do I enforce the validation?** If possible, I'd like to avoid calling a validator explicitely in each method of the repository.

I've seen many examples online that I've tried to reproduce (From Baeldung to DZone, with of course a lot of questions on this very website, including [this interesting one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13745848/5018771)), still unsuccessful. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to implement a `integration test` if you want to use `repository` via so that `javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException` is thrown by showing `must not be blank` but if you want to test only  those validations then you will have to test by using a validator by following way:

1.- Add the following dependency:

```
<dependency> 
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.13.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

2.- Add a custom validation tests for the `Customer` fields

```
import javax.validation.Validation;
import javax.validation.Validator;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class CustomerValidationTest {

    private Validator validator;

    @Before
    public void setupValidatorInstance() {
        validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();
    }

    @Test
    public void whenNotEmptyPassword_thenNoConstraintViolations() {
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        customer.setPassword("");
        Set<ConstraintViolation<Customer>> violations = validator.validate(customer);

        assertThat(violations.size()).isEqualTo(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: What should I change to make my class an `integration test`? I get the separate test for checking each validation but I don't understand the beginning of your answer

Comment: You need a `datasource` loaded you might use the following `embedded database` for testing  `@AutoConfigureEmbeddedDatabase` annotation,  let me share an answer by using `integration test` https://stackoverflow.com/a/49011982/10426557 let me know if this helps you. thanks, kind regards.

Comment: Ok I'll test it. Is there no way to just mock my DB connection and have the rest of the method executed, including @Valid checks? I don't understand why having a "real" DB (albeit in memory) is part of the solution...

Comment: `mocking` is not a real environment then if you want that the `ConstraintViolationException` is thrown so that you can validate its content then should create an `embedded database`  in order to simulate a `real datasource`